# Netbeans paint component

Tags: java, swing, drawing, paintcomponent

Is this correct direction to draw a point on panel? Everything is working fine but I don't know if it is a correct way to draw something.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    Dimension size = getSize();

    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    for(int i=0;i<last;i++) {
        int x = i*(800/last);
        int y = one[i];
        g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    }

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    progr progr= new progr();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    frame.add(new progr()); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), and edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approch.

Comment: Yes, overriding `paintComponent()` and invoking `super.paintComponent()` is the proper way to do custom painting. I don't know what your painting code is supposed to do since you didn't post a SSCCE so I don't know if there is any better way to do what you want or not.